# Javascript NewForm to EditForm on Save

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

Can someone advise how to have users redirect from New form to edit form on save of the same item?

Start - Newform URL: http://sharepoint.com/sites/project/lists/NewForm.aspx

On Save go to the form/item just saved - Editform URL: http://mysharepoint.com/sites/project/lists/EditForm.aspx?ID=66

Comment: this would be difficult until and unless you are using custom new form and custom javascript to create items in list because you will never know id of until server side code is executed and new item is created....still from where user is opting to create new item ? is it list view page ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you don't know the ID yet of the new item.

So a workaround would be to

- Create View: Last Inserted Item, displaying the most recent item
- Make the New Form goto that View with the standard SharePoint QueryString `source` parameter
- Add some JS to open the displayed Item

Or you could use the default AllItems View and some more lines of JavaScript to check if you came from the NewForm and get the most recent added item.